React onClick not working with custom component
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Board() {
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
  const [xIsNext, setXIsNext] = useState(true)
  
  function handleClick(box) {
    console.log("In handleClick function")
    if (squares[box] || calculateWinner(squares)){
      return;
    }
    const nextSquares = squares.slice();
    if (xIsNext) {
      nextSquares[box] = "X";
    }
    else {
      nextSquares[box] = "O";
    }
    setXIsNext(!xIsNext)
    setSquares(nextSquares)
  }

  function handleReset() {
    console.log("In handleReset function")
    setSquares(Array(9).fill(null));
  }

  const winner = calculateWinner(squares);
  let status;
  if (winner) {
    status = "Winner: " + winner;
  }
  else {
    status = "Next Player: " + (xIsNext ? "X" : "O");
  }

  return (
  <>
    <div className="status">{status}</div>
    <div className="board-row">
      <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(0)} />
      <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)} />
      <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
      <Square value={squares[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)} />
      <Square value={squares[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)} />
      <Square value={squares[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
      <Square value={squares[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)} />
      <Square value={squares[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)} />
      <Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} />
    </div>
    <div className="reset">
      <Reset onResetClick={() => handleReset}/>
    </div>
  </>
  );
}

function Square({ value, onSquareClick }) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={onSquareClick}>
      {value}
    </button>
  );
}

function Reset( {onResetClick} ) {
  return (
    <button className="reset" onClick={onResetClick}>
      Reset Game
    </button>
  );
}

function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

I am learning React and I followed a tutorial to create a TicTacToe game. I have all the functionality working but I wanted to try adding my own Reset button. I added the component:
<div className="reset">
      <Reset onResetClick={() => handleReset}/>
</div>

and then I added the rest of the logic:
function handleReset() {
    console.log("In handleReset function")
    setSquares(Array(9).fill(null));
  }

function Reset( {onResetClick} ) {
  return (
    <button className="reset" onClick={onResetClick}>
      Reset Game
    </button>
  );
}

but I do not get a reset of the array and the log does not output when I click the Reset Game button.

onResetClick={() => handleReset} This function does nothing. It refers to handleReset, but does not call it. Did you mean onResetClick={() => handleReset()} or onResetClick={handleReset}?

Yep... that was my mistake. I new it was something small. Thank you!

You should change <Reset onResetClick={() => handleReset}/> to <Reset onResetClick={() => handleReset()}/>
